# Apk Analyser showing question mark on library file.so

Tags: android, apk, abi, pspdfkit

Adding ABI split code in gradle :

```
android {
    splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true
            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
            reset()
            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            // Specifies that we want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk true
        }
    }

}
```

giving error while using library :

```
2020-01-22 16:41:06.442 6936-6936/clubwise.com.fitsense W/System.err: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/x86/libpspdfkit.so
```

After analyzing app found that library file showing question mark.

What is wrong in my code.

[image: This is how it is looking in app anaylser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution here :

[PSPdf guide for the specified problem](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/android/current/troubleshooting/abi-set-not-compatible/)